# Getting error while running DB crud in parallel. inside Tas.Run(() => {})

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am using ef core 6 with repository pattern and unit of work.

I am doing the DI for ApplicationDBContext and repository like this.

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), 
    providers => providers.EnableRetryOnFailure(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), null))
);

services.AddScoped<ISupplierRepository, SupplierRepository>();

services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

Now for initializing the service class where the db crud code is written using factory pattern mentioned below

```cs
using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    _messageFactory = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IAvroMessageFactory>();
    messageHandler = _messageFactory.GetMessageHandler(serviceName);

    if (await messageHandler.AddMessage(messageValue)) // crud logic is written here
    {
    }
}
```

Now I wanted to call this addmessage inside

```cs
Task.Run(() => {

});
```

I am getting this below error while I am running that inside task.run
"The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked"

I wanted to run the db crud operation running in parallel.

Comment: Create new `DbContext` for each `Task.Run`. `DbContext` is not thread safe.

Comment: There is clearly not enough info here to explain the exact reason for the error. The error itself is pretty clear - you are trying to add an entity which was already added to the context at some point.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv This I though of but for that I have to change the application structure. So that is not a feasible for now.. Any other way we can achieve DB crud in parallel.

Comment: There is no other ways. DbContext is not thread safe.  Create Scope for each Task.Run and each scope will have new `DbContext`.